# Isomorphism of stalks induces isomorphism of open neighbourhoods

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $k$ be a field and $X, Y$ k-schemes locally of finite type.

Let $x\in X, y\in Y$, and $g: \mathscr O_{Y,y} \to \mathscr O_{X,x}$ be an isomorphism of k-algebras.

Prove $\exists U, V$ open neigbourhoods of $x,y$ and $\exists h:U\to V$ an isomorphism of k-schemes that induces $g$.

My attempt:

$X,Y$ are locally of finite type over $k$, so locally noetherian.
Hence there are neighbourhoods $x\in U'\subset X, y\in V'\subset Y$ s.t. $U'=\operatorname{Spec} A, V'=\operatorname{Spec} B$ for some noetherian rings $A,B$.

Since $\mathscr O_{Y,y} = B_b=\mathscr O_Y(D(b))$ and $\mathscr O_{X,x} = A_a=\mathscr O_X(D(a))$ for some $a\in A, b\in B$ we have an induced isomorphism $h:\ \ D(a)\to D(b)$ that induces $g$.  (here notation $A_a$ means localization at $a\in A$)

Setting $U:=D(a)\subset U',V:=D(b)\subset V'$ we are done.

I suspect lots of mistakes in this proof as I am new to scheme theory.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Why have you written "skew field"? It doesn't really make sense to talk about schemes in the non-commutative setting.

Comment: Indeed! it adds nothing to the question It was just the setup of the exercise we had in class. I will fix it, thank you!

Comment: It is not true that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y} =B_{b}$ for some element $b \in B$, rather, it will be an inductive limit of such things (which is probably what the exercise wants you to use).